# Call a function referenced in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am super new to AngularJS and create a new menu on the nav bar that populates and displays the name of an object once user logs in. I want to be able to click on the item and display another variable of the object in a alert box. I am using a directive to populate the object and it looks as follows:

```
angular.module('angularWebApp.headerDirectives', [])
.directive('machineList', function(){
  // Runs during compile
  return {
    // name: '',
    // priority: 1,
    // terminal: true,
    // scope: {}, // {} = isolate, true = child, false/undefined = no change
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude, $http) {
      $scope.machineObj = [];
      $scope.alertMe = function($keyword){
        alert($keyword.Address);
      };
      if($scope.user !== undefined) {
          if($scope.user.Key.constructor === Array) {
            angular.forEach($scope.user.Key, function(software_key, key){
                $http.get('URL' + software_key + '/DATA').
              success(function(data/*, status, headers, config*/) {
                if(data.id === 'error') {
                  console.log(data);
                } else {
                  $scope.machineList = data;
                  angular.forEach($scope.machineList,function(machine,index){
                    $scope.machineObj.push({
                      Name: machine.Name,
                      Address: machine.Address,
                      Key: machine.Key
                    });

                  });
                }
              }).
              error(function(data/*, status, headers, config*/) {
                alert(data);
              });
            });

          }
    } else {
      $http.get('URL' + $scope.user.key + '/DATA').
          success(function(data/*, status, headers, config*/) {
        if(data.id === 'error') {
          console.log(data);
        } else {

          angular.forEach($scope.machineList,function(machine,index){
            $scope.machineObj.push({
              Name: machine.Name,
              Address: machine.Address,
              Key: machine.SoftwareKey
            });

          });
          console.log($scope.machineObj);
        }
      }).
      error(function(data/*, status, headers, config*/) {
        alert(data);
      });
    }
},
// require: 'ngModel', // Array = multiple requires, ? = optional, ^ = check parent elements
restrict: 'AE', // E = Element, A = Attribute, C = Class, M = Comment
template: '<li ng-machine ng-repeat="machine in machineObj" class="text-center"><a ng-href="" ng-click="alertMe(machine)">{{::machine.Name}}</a></li>',
// templateUrl: '',
replace: true,
// transclude: true,
// compile: function(tElement, tAttrs, function transclude(function(scope, cloneLinkingFn){ return function linking(scope, elm, attrs){}})),
//link: function(scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller, $http) {}
  };
});
```

Sorry for formatting. Then I have the HTML which is as follows:

```
< li ng-switch-when="true">
    <a href="" class="machines dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></a>
    < ul class="dropdown-menu">
        < machine-List>
        < /machine-List>
    < /ul>
< /li>
```

Machine-List is replaced with the template I define in the directive and the http.get completes successfully. It is just getting a function to call when a user selects a menu item that seems to be the issue. I appreciate any help in advance!

### Update For Ralfe Pastbin

This is the output I get:

```
Initialising Scope.
headerDirectives.js:129 User exists
headerDirectives.js:129 Key is an array
headerDirectives.js:129 Processing data.
headerDirectives.js:67 [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object,Object, Object, Object, Object]0: Object1: Object2: Object3: Object4: Object5: Object6: Object7: Object8: Object9: Objectlength: 10__proto__: Array[0]
```

Last line is my console.log

Comment: try putting an empty scope variable on your directive to make an isolated scope.

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: No errors in console @OmriAharon. Delta I am unsure of how to do this could you shoot some code to ground me on what to do? Sorry about my newness to NG.

Comment: What's the purpose of `::` in the `{{::machine.Name}}` btw ?

Comment: I see you have `<li ng-machine` in your template. What does the ng-machine do? If that is another directive, then you might be creating a new child scope, and the alertMe() function might not be accessible.

Comment: @OmriAharon, the `::` does a bind-once.

Comment: @ralfe I dont have another directive so I assume it would be good to remove it as I was going to use it as a require: 'A' but it ended up being 'E'

Comment: Any chance you can reproduce this on fiddler?

Answer (score 0):

Within the controller, you can attach functions to the scope like this:

```
$scope.someFunction = function(myParam1) {
    // Do something amazing here.
};
```

Then, you can access that function from the view like this:

```
<span class='btn btn-primary' ng-click='someFunction(4)'>Click Me</span>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @ralfe the issue I think is somewhere around here in the directive - 

template: '<li ng-machine ng-repeat="machine in machineObj" class="text-center"><a ng-href="" ng-click="alertMe(machine)">{{::machine.Name}}</a></li>', - i then have a function higher up in the directive for and alert box. Not sure why it wouldnt work as it is as you say now but no luck.

Comment: @BinaryWasteland - Take a look at my comment on your question.

Comment: @ralfe Answered it I believe

Comment: @BinaryWasteland - Try using this code and show us the console output: http://pastebin.com/neS771vS

Comment: @Ralfe Updated post up top with output

Comment: @BinaryWasteland - Is there any chance you can share more of your code with us? Like on JSFiddle?